# Excel formula to get time difference as a decimal number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a table like this (the `C` column is blank):

```
     A          B           C

1  19:30      23:00       (3.50)

2  14:15      18:30       (4.25)
```

I need to calculate the time difference in each row between column `A` and column `B` (always `B` - `A`), and put it in column `C` as a decimal number (as shown inside the parentheses).

Which formula should I use? Is it possible to generate a general formula, so I won't have to change the row number every time (maybe `INDIRECT`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use MOD that will also work when the times cross midnight, e.g. in C2

`=MOD(B2-A2,1)*24`

copy formula down column and the row numbers will change automaticaly for each row

Answer (score 7):

This will do the job:

```
=(B1-A1)*24
```

You might need to format the cell as number, not time!